# How to use delve debugger to step through a executable?

Tags: go, delve

I would like to step through the execution of a command -

`rosetta-cli check:construction --configuration-file bitcoin_testnet/config.json`

I refer to this command as alpha for the rest of this posting.

rosetta-cli is a golang binary which lives in ~/go/bin and takes some flags - as illustrated above.

I am trying to map out the series of calls that alpha goes through until it reaches the error. For example: alpha calls f1 which then calls f2 at which point there is an error. I would like to step through this process to gain a better understanding of where the problem is.

How can I accomplish this with delve, or a similar debugging tool?

Edit: A bonus would be if I could step line by line through the offending functions and see what the code which caused them to panic looked like at the time it was run.

```
func f2(){
// request some data
// some error causes the server to panic
// return some data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not exactly what I wanted I found away to achieve the desired result using vscode.

Just add this to you .vscode/launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Delve",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "debug",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/<myfolder>/<myprogram>",
            "env": {},
            "port": 9090,
            "args": ["run","--flag", "foo"]
        }
    ]
}
```